# Ubuntu 20.04で標準ユーザに対して操作を制限したい

Tags: linux, ubuntu

アプリケーション自体を起動できないようにしたり、
設定画面から変更できる項目を消したりなどの制限を行いたいのですが、
どのような方法があるでしょうか。

rbash、AuthorizedKeysFileなどを考えましたが、
ターミナルなどのアプリケーション自体も起動できないようにしたかったため、方法から外しました。

Ubuntuの起動はLive USBです。
標準ユーザに対してはGUIでログイン後、ブラウザ(Firefox)と
設定画面（ネットワーク設定やディスプレイ設定など一部のみ）だけ
操作を許可したいと考えています。

具体的な方法というよりも、何か手段があればご教示ください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

少し調べただけなので、詳細な手順は回答できませんが、**dconf** という仕組みが使えるかもしれません。
(イメージとしては Windows のグループポリシーのようなもの？)

[How to harden a ubuntu desktop? - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/103110)

[GSETTINGS および DCONF を使用したデスクトップの設定 - Red Hat Customer Portal](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/ja-jp/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/desktop_migration_and_administration_guide/configuration-overview-gsettings-dconf)

> dconf はユーザー設定を管理するキーベースの設定システムです。これは Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 で使用される GSettings のバックエンドです。dconf は、GDM、アプリケーション、およびプロキシー設定を含む複数の異なる設定を管理します。

この中で、"ロックダウンモード" というのを使用すれば、予め定義したルールに従って、ユーザーが特定の操作や設定を変更できないようにすることができるようです。

余談として一つ気になったのは、LiveUSB の環境だとカスタマイズした状態のOSイメージを用意してメディアにインストールする必要が出てくるかと思います。